# How to create .zip file from my document directory?

Tags: ios

I'd like to create a ZIP file from my document directory.

I'd also like to send it as an email attachment.

Comment: What did you already try? We would gladly help you solving problems, but we do not write the code. So please expand your question with some more information and the failing code.

Comment: i want to create iphone application which require a functionality that i have a directory  which i want to zipped it and send as mail attachment from my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZipArchive is an Objective-C class to compress or uncompress zip files, which is base on open source code "MiniZip".

It can be used for iPhone application development, and cocoa on Mac OSX as well.

see this : http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list

Answer (score 6):

SSZipArchive, in active development on GitHub, was developed from ZipArchive:

https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive

Comment: Looked great - but sadly no longer works as of 2014 with iOS 7 and 7.1 SDKs.

Comment: @JayVersluis I've updated my answer to point to the actively developed fork.

Answer (score 0):

Objective Zip does a great job. Simply checkout the project and run it for a demo:

https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip

Works fine with Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1